# generate multiple conditional statements from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a list like this

```
a = [1,0,6,9,6,0,6,0,1,4,0,7,5,0]
```

I want to create a conditional statement like this:

```
if a[1,3,8,13] != 0:
    do something
```

And this code is obviously wrong. It has to be like this:

```
if a[1] != 0 and a[3] != 0 and a[8] != 0 and a[13] != 0:
    do something
```

I want to know if there is any more elegant way for writing the multiple conditional statements using lambda or loop in my case. Let say my list is like 100 in length, and I need to make a conditional statements for 57 columns of the list. I probably don't want to write them all out in such a fashion...
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1.

You can use `all`:

```
if all(a[i] != 0 for i in [1,3,8,13]): # => a[i] != 0 for every i 
    #do smth
```

Or just the same with `any`:

```
if not any(a[i] == 0 for i in [1,3,8,13]): # => there is no such i that a[i] == 0
    #do smth                               # => a[i] != 0 for every i
```

---

#### 2.

Alternatively, you can use some functional programming stuff.
For example, you can try `filter`:

```
a = [1,0,6,9,6,0,6,0,1,4,0,7,5,0]
idxs_to_check = [1,3,8,13]

f = list(filter(lambda i: a[i] != 0, idxs_to_check))
if f == idxs_to_check:
    print('Meow')
```

Or, a similar condition in one line:

```
if not list(filter(lambda i: a[i] == 0, [1,3,8,13])): 
    print('Meow')
```

---

#### 3.

Finally, in your particular case, you can use the fact that the product of a list containing zero is zero:

```
from numpy import prod

if prod([a[i] for i in [1,3,8,13]]):
    print("Woof")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
a = [1,0,6,9,6,0,6,0,1,4,0,7,5,0]

if a[1] or a[2] or a[8] or a[13] != a[2]:
      print (“something”) #this part cuz I’m not sure what ur doing here
```

I don’t really know if this works, hopefully it does.
But again this might get repetitive. So u might want to result to

```
if all(a[i] != 0 for i in [1,3,8,13]
```

Basically ur iterating through each of ur chosen positions in the list to check if position 0 is the same

Hope this helps!